# include in a separate function results in undefined variables?

Tags: php

This doesn't work, results in undefined variables in `order-details.php`

```
public function getJobById($jobId)
{
    $orderDetails = $this->jobModel->getJobById($jobId);
    $payments = $this->paymentModel->getAllPaymentsForJobOrder($jobId);
    $this->loadOrderDetailsPage();
}

public function loadOrderDetailsPage()
{
    include './order-details.php';
}
```

This works as expected:

```
public function getJobById($jobId)
{
    $orderDetails = $this->jobModel->getJobById($jobId);
    $payments = $this->paymentModel->getAllPaymentsForJobOrder($jobId);
    include './order-details.php';
}
```

I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: This is a *very* strange way to structure your code.  But I suppose you could pass your variables to your second function as function arguments.  Basically they're undefined because you're in the context of a new function, and those variables are only in the scope of the first function.  I suspect whatever functionality goal you have would likely be better achieved some other way though, on a larger scope than what's presented here in this small example.

Comment: @David I see. Basically I'm trying to imitate the MVC behavior, and before, I've had a function that was solely for displaying a view. Honestly I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it or I should just load the view directly in the function, without using a second function solely for just displaying it.

Comment: You are getting MVC all wrong... [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000)

Comment: @IROEGBU How so? The code above is in my controller, not in my model, if that's what you meant based on the link you gave.